# SQL Convert duplicate rows to unique columns and join

Tags: sql, join

trying to join some tables, with some of them containing multiple rows that describe the same type of data for that entity.
For example if I have these 2 tables:

[image]

And I try to join the table to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Which dbms is this? What's the maximum number of duplicates or is there any? Do the different title/descriptions need to be in separate columns or could a list work?

Comment: @EdmCoff - it's MSSQL. Yes, they need to be in separate columns.

Comment: How many columns? Could there be hundreds?

Comment: @EdmCoff - for now the extra values would 3 pairs, so 6 columns, but could technically be a bit more, not too crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I'd be skeptical of requirements that need arbitrary numbers of columns. It would be preferable if you could join the tables and then the consuming system could format it the way you want it. Or, if you need human-readable data directly from the query, I'd generally prefer a list using `string_agg` like:

```
SELECT p.productid, productname, STRING_AGG(infotitle+','+infodescription, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY infotitle) info
FROM products p INNER JOIN infos i
  ON p.productid = i.productid
GROUP BY p.productid, productname
```

Having said all that, if you really want your expected output, you could use correlated subqueries:

```
WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT *, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY productid ORDER BY i.infoid) rn
 FROM infos i
)
SELECT p.*,
 (SELECT infotitle FROM cte i WHERE i.productid = p.productid AND i.rn = 1) infotitle1,
 (SELECT infodescription FROM cte i WHERE i.productid = p.productid AND i.rn = 1) infodescription1, 
 (SELECT infotitle FROM cte i WHERE i.productid = p.productid AND i.rn = 2) infotitle2,
 (SELECT infodescription FROM cte i WHERE i.productid = p.productid AND i.rn = 2) infodescription2,
 (SELECT infotitle FROM cte i WHERE i.productid = p.productid AND i.rn = 3) infotitle3,
 (SELECT infodescription FROM cte i WHERE i.productid = p.productid AND i.rn = 3) infodescription3
FROM products p
```

The idea is that the common table expression gets the row number within the `productid` group so that the subqueries within the `select` can pull the relevant values.

Or you could use a `pivot`:

```
with cte AS
(
  SELECT productid, infotitle value, 'infotitle' + CAST(row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY productid ORDER BY infoid) as varchar) title
  FROM infos
  UNION ALL
  SELECT productid, infodescription, 'infodescription' + CAST(row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY productid ORDER BY infoid) as varchar)
  FROM infos
)
SELECT *
FROM
  (
   SELECT p.productname, i.*
   FROM products p INNER JOIN cte i
    ON p.productid = i.productid
  ) c
PIVOT
(
 max(value) FOR title IN ([infotitle1], [infodescription1], [infotitle2], [infodescription2], [infotitle3], [infodescription3])
) p
```

You can see both of these [examples working in this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EN_1ZOBa).

As you can see, something like this will be messy to maintain. If you need to dynamically change the number of columns, you might be better off using a function or script that can dynamically generate the query you need.